# Are square configurations the only critical points of the energy on the circle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, nonlinear-optimization, physics, symmetry, multivariable-calculus

$\newcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}^1}$
$\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}$Let$$M=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in  (\S)^4\,\, |\,\, \text{ all the } x_i \, \text{ are distinct}\} $$

Define $E:M \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$E(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\sum_{i < j}\frac{1}{\| x_i - x_j \|},$$

where $\| x_i - x_j \|$ denotes the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Question:** Does $E$ have any critical points besides square configurations?

---

**Analysis:**

Let $\beta(t)$ be a path in $\S$, $\beta(0)=x_4, \dot \beta(0)=x_{4}^{\perp} \in T_{x_4}\S$. Then
$$dE_p(0,0,0,x_{4}^{\perp})=\sum_{i=1}^3 \| x_i - x_4 \|^{-3}\langle x_i,x_{4}^{\perp}\rangle, \tag{1}$$

Let $\theta_{ij}$ denote the angle between $x_j,x_i$ **measured from $j$ to $i$**. Choosing $x_i^\perp$ to be counter clockwise, it holds that
$$
\langle x_i,x_{j}^{\perp}\rangle=\sin\theta_{ij}.
$$
For $i\neq j$, set $
a_{ij}:=\lambda_{ij} \sin\theta_{ij}
$, where $$\lambda_{ij}:= \| x_i - x_j \|^{-3}=\big(2|\sin(\theta_{ij}/2)|\big)^{-3}.$$

Then, $dE_p=0$ if and only if
$$
\sum_{j \neq i} \la_{ij}\langle x_j,x_i^\perp  \rangle=0
$$
or
$$
\sum_{j \neq i} |\sin(\theta_{ij}/2)|^{-3}\sin(\theta_{ij})=0. \tag{2}
$$
for every $1 \le i \le 4$.

Comment: $1/\sin x$ is strictly convex on $[0,\pi]$ and the domain $\theta_1<\theta_2<\dots<\theta_n<\theta_1+2\pi$ is convex, so, apparently, the answer is "It does not".

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned up the presentation, it is much shorter now. Can you please elaborate on how do you suggest to analyze the equation $(2)$ in the end of the question's body using convexity?

Comment: I suggest not to analyze it at all but instead note that a strictly convex function cannot have more than one critical point in a convex domain (when I say "strictly convex", I, of course, factor trivial shift invariance out by, say, fixing $\theta_1$)

Comment: More generally, the regular n-gons are the only critical points of this kind of energy function when you use $n$ points in the circle.  I think this has been pointed out in the literature several times.